# Getting blog text to wrap around menu DIV when menu rendered last

Tags: css, wordpress, templates, css-float

I am working with WordPress and I am trying to modify my template so that on my blog pages. I have a menu on the right hand side of the page while the blog content is on the left. The problem I am having is that all the space under the menu `<div>` is wasted and I would like to have the blog content wrap/flow around the menu `<div>`. Normally I would float the menu `<div>` to the right, however the WordPress engine outputs this `<div>` after the blog content so I am not sure how to float it to the upper right corner of the page.

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqR7N/) example to illustrate.

Comment: I think it should be possible to edit your template completely, so that the output is in the right order.

Comment: If you don't know JavaScript support is enabled then your right, this seems like the only way to go. However, it does mean editing a fair amount of template files. I like @roddy-of-the-frozen-peas's suggestion as with one line you could move the menu DIV. Of course it depends on JavaScript being enabled as well as knowing where to place the jQuery snippet in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a short bit of JavaScript to move the menu as necessary. See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7mmu/1/) I forked from yours.

Essentially I modified the HTML to add ids to the menu and the blog content, something like this:

```
<div id="blog">
    <p>...</p>
</div>
<div id="menu">
    ...
</div>
```

Then I styled them like so in CSS. Note that the menu has an explicit width but the blog content itself does not.

```
#blog { }
#menu {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Then I used a quick bit of JQuery to move the menu into the blog so that it can float right and the text will wrap around it:

```
$('#blog').prepend($('#menu').remove());​
```

Essentially what the JavaScript does is it removes the menu from the dom and then inserts it as the first child in `#blog`.
​

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. Now I just need to figure out where to insert the jQuery.

Comment: Also, thanks for your followup JSFiddle for the example. It always helps to have an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set float of menu to right and put it on top of the post div.

For example, the CSS should be like this:

```
#post {width: 500px;}
#menu {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #6666FF;
    border: solid 1px #333;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="post">
<div id="menu">lorep ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP indicated that the menu is generated *after* the blog content, so I don't think they can move it anywhere.

Comment: Oops. Sorry didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap text around a div like you would do with an image e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/Nbpen/

Comment: You moved the menu. The OP indicated that the menu is generated *after* the blog content.